# How to take off class when click on another element and show relative content

Tags: javascript

I got the following code, but when I click the menu, it uses `.active` class but when I click another element it doesn't remove the class but adds the clicked item e.g. If I have more menu and content I have to do a lot `if else`

How can I use `active` class on the element that had been clicked and show its content only?

```js
const app = document.querySelector("#app");

/**
 *1. create div
 * attach a class to it
 * add menu items to it
 * attach item to div 1
 * attach div to app
 * show each div content when that div is clicked e.g. when description is clicked, it show description div
 * When clicked it showed shows its content and hides other
 */
const div = document.createElement("div");
div.className = "navigation";
const ul = document.createElement("ul");
const li = document.createElement("li");;
// const items = ["Description", "Delivery","Delivery"];
// items.forEach((item)=>{
//   li.textContent += item
//   ul.appendChild(li);
// })
ul.innerHTML = `
 <li><a href="#">Description</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Delivery</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Returns</a></li>
`
div.appendChild(ul);
app.insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin",div);

const contentDiv = document.createElement("div");
contentDiv.className = "contentDescription";
contentDiv.innerHTML = `
<h2>Description</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus facere enim repudiandae iusto unde 
    quam a sapiente libero ullam consequuntur!</p>
`
div.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", contentDiv)
const nodeToArray = document.querySelectorAll("li");

nodeToArray.forEach((arr)=>{
    arr.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
       if(e.target.innerText == 'Description'){
            e.target.className ="active"
       }else if(e.target.innerText == 'Delivery'){
           e.target.className = "active";
           document.querySelector(".contentDescription").style.display = "none"
       }
    })
})
```

```css
li{
    list-style: none;
}
ul{
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
.active{
   border-bottom:2px solid black;
}
```

```html
    <div id="app">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're asking for a way to create a menu that has different sub-menus. When a submenu is clicked, it gains the `.active` class and any other active sub-menu is de-`active`-ated right? You also want to ensure that the description text is shown only when the description link is clicked.

In that case, you need to make use of a concept called [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation).
Instead of attaching a click listener to each menu item, just add one listener to the main menu itself that will manage the submenu clicks.

So first of all:

- give your sub-menu items a class of 'sub-menu'
- give the description item a class, or maybe an id, that you can use to uniquely identify it. A `.menu-description` should suffice.

```html
<div class="navigation">
    <ul id="menu">                                         
        <li class="sub-menu menu-description">Description</li>
        <li class="sub-menu">Delivery</li>
        <li class="sub-menu">Returns</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="contentDescription">Lorem ipsum...</div>
</div>
```

The javascript goes like so:

```js
let menu = document.querySelector('#menu');
menu.addEventListener('click', e => {
    // the newly clicked menu item
    let current = e.target.closest('.sub-menu');
    if (! current) {
        return;
    }

    // the previously active menu item
    let prev = menu.querySelector('.sub-menu.active');
    if (prev) {
        prev.classList.remove('active');
    }

    current.classList.add('active');

    // Hide the description text if the clicked sub-menu is not the description-link
    let hideMenu = !current.classList.includes('.menu-description'); 
    menu.querySelector('.contentDescription').hidden = hideMenu;
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this but can u show me HTML for the example u give. `menu` is confusing to know what is it.

Comment: In think example u are check for `.menu-description` but why u using `menu.querySelector('.contentDescription').hidden = !hideMenu`

Comment: @localhost I've added the HTML and some explanations